# Gnote Synchronization

Tags: tomboy, gnote

Ubuntu One has shutdown Tomboy synchronization.

As a workaround, I have installed Gnote and it works very well, but I need somewhere to sync my notes.  I would like to have access to them not only from all my computers, but from my (Android) Nexus phone as well.

Are there any internet servers or other options for gnote sync?

Edit:
I'm sorry for not being more precise in my question, English are not my first language.
Tomboy has been my favorite notes program for a long time. But after they shutdown, first the webinterface and then the U1 sync, I been looking for a replacement.
Trying to use Gnote instead, might not be the solution for me at all. It is really just to find something that meets my needs and that work's, Gnote or Tomboy works fine. (And are not at some commercial company).
On my Nexus phone Tomdroid has been giving me access to my Tomboy notes.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention to my question.
I am aware of the question/answers that my question has been marked as a duplicate of.
But the suggested solution of file sync to cloud storage has one problem. There are no access for an Android app?

Comment: Okay,  I'll see if we can get this re-opened.  In the meanwhile could you edit your question to be much more specific about the android app part?   Thanks.

Comment: Why is installing Gnote a workaround for you? You could also use Tomboy in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/sincronizacion-de-notas-en-la-nube/

Basically, the trick is to set a symbolic-link from the folder where the notes are saved to a synchronized folder (in the example it's Dropbox, but I'm doing it with Seafile, that is Free Software under AGPL, and it works perfect, http://seafile.com/en/home/ ).

The page linked is in spanish, if you need some translation, let me know :)

Best regards!